# Compare two SQL tables by rows and columns

Tags: sql, compare

hoping someone can help. Need to compare data within 2 identical tables within 2 different databases.

Ideally, this solution would be able to be repurposed for any table/field pair. So this piece of logic would take two table names (the ones to compare) as parameters. Assuming tables have primary keys on them, the code will use primary keys to align two tables row-by-row, and from there, it's field by field comparison. It's vital to compare by row, but also by column in order to see if there are any differences between the 2 tables in terms of data.

I see a few solutions to compare two tables row by row, but I haven't been able to find anything that also incorporates column by column comparison within each row of both tables. Hoping to please get some help with this SQL code, glad to answer any questions.

Thanks guys.

This compares all data from two tables by rows

```
SELECT * FROM table1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM table2 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM table1
```

but I also need to compare all data in each row by columns

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Kindly recheck the process of EXCEPT, INTERSECT & UNION. Whatever you're asking the same thing is already there.  Based on your requirement you can pick any of those operators.

Comment: Which RDBMS and version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Replace table1 and table2 with the names of your actual tables, and primary_key_columns with the primary key columns in your tables. Rows from both tables are merged in this query, a source identification ('table1' or 'table2') is assigned, rows are grouped by the primary key columns, groups with a count of 1 (indicating a difference) are eliminated, and the result is sorted by the primary key columns. This query compares data row by row and column by column by using the primary key to align rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 'table1' AS source, t1.*
  FROM table1 t1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'table2' AS source, t2.*
  FROM table2 t2
) AS combined
GROUP BY primary_key_columns
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY primary_key_columns;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current query is almost correct, but you have not forced the precedence to make sure the two `EXCEPT`s are `UNION`ed together. Your current query is equivalent to:

```
(
    (SELECT * FROM table1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM table2)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM table2
)
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

You need to add parentheses around the two queries to be `UNION`ed:

```
(
    SELECT * FROM table1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM table2
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT * FROM table2
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM table1
);
```

If using MySQL (>= 8.0.19 for [`TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table.html), and >= 8.0.31 for [`EXCEPT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/except.html)), you can switch the `SELECT * FROM` to just `TABLE`:

```
(TABLE table1 EXCEPT TABLE table2)
UNION ALL
(TABLE table2 EXCEPT TABLE table1);
```

Given table1:

| id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | some text blah blah blah |
| 2 | 2 | some text blah blah blah |
| 3 | 2 | some text blah blah blah |
| 4 | 3 | some text blah blah blah |
| 5 | 2 | some text blah blah blah |
| 7 | 2 | some text blah blah blah |

and table2:

| id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | some text blah blah blah |
| 2 | 2 | some text blah blah blah bl4h |
| 3 | 3 | some text blah blah blah |
| 4 | 2 | some text blah blah blah |
| 6 | 2 | some text blah blah blah |
| 7 | 2 | some text blah blah blah |

```
(SELECT * FROM table1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM table2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM table2 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM table1)
ORDER BY id;
```

outputs:

| id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | some text blah blah blah |
| 2 | 2 | some text blah blah blah bl4h |
| 3 | 2 | some text blah blah blah |
| 3 | 3 | some text blah blah blah |
| 4 | 2 | some text blah blah blah |
| 4 | 3 | some text blah blah blah |
| 5 | 2 | some text blah blah blah |
| 6 | 2 | some text blah blah blah |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/e31w1ZLB), using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: *additional overhead of UNION ALL* what additional overhead? If anything `UNION` has more overhead as it implies `DISTINCT` which `UNION ALL` does not

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you. My head was clearly on backwards when I wrote that!